# Does kubernetes has an api that can create multiple kind resources at the same time

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

Now I have a situation that I have same yaml files, each of them contains things like deployment, service, ingress, etc. I have to create them concurrently, I tyied ansible to achive if but failed, so I want to know if kubernetes has an **API endpoint** can post the yaml file to it and create resources like what the command `kubectl create -f sample.yaml` did.You can also give me other advice to achive my purpose if you like.

Comment: A `.yaml` file with all contents but it may not meet your `concurrent` requirement.

Comment: what is your requirement for concurency cause it sounds pretty exotic. Maybe kube has a different way of solving your actual concern.

Comment: I can also accept if there's a way to post my yaml file to kubernetes api and create all resources in it, once a file.

Answer (score 1):

> I can also accept if there's a way to post my yaml file to kubernetes api and create all resources in it

Then you can simply concatenate all individual yaml files into one big yaml file but each separted by `---` in between.

For example to install kubernetes-dashboard you simply use: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`, examination of this yaml file reveals structure you need (excerpt below):

```
...

# ------------------- Dashboard Secret ------------------- #

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
  namespace: kube-system
type: Opaque

---
# ------------------- Dashboard Service Account ------------------- #

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system

---
# ------------------- Dashboard Role & Role Binding ------------------- #

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-minimal

...
```

where each block between comments could be separate yaml file. Note that comments are optional and separator between contents of individual yaml files is `---`.

Just some sidenotes:

- although this is somewhat practical for final deployments, if you glue all of your individual yaml files into such a mega-all-in-one.yaml file then everything you do to it - (create/update/apply/delete...) you do to all resources listed inside.
- If it is not "shared" file to be executed from some network resource, it then may be easier to use `--recursive` switch to kubectl as detailed in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/) and run against folder that contains all individual yaml files. This way you retain capability to individually pick any yaml file, and can deploy/delete/apply... all at once if you choose so...

Comment: There's some problem that I cannot execute command on remote machine, I just want to post the yaml to an url and achive the same effect as what you mentioned above.

Comment: Have you solved your question ? I have the same requirement.